# The name 'SqlDataSourceEnumerator' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, sqldatasource

In a C# .net 5 program in Visual Studio I am testing a code that is using SqlDataSourceEnumerator

```
public static List<SqlServerInstance> LocateSqlInstances()
{
    List<SqlServerInstance> results = new List<SqlServerInstance>();

    using (DataTable sqlSources = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources())
    {
        foreach (DataRow source in sqlSources.Rows)
        {
            string servername;
            string instancename = source["InstanceName"].ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instancename))
            {
                servername = source["ServerName"].ToString() + '\\' + instancename;
            }
            else
            {
                servername = source["ServerName"].ToString();
            }

            results.Add(new SqlServerInstance() { ServerInstance = servername, Version = source["Version"].ToString() });
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Although I have using System.Data; I get

> Error CS0103  The name 'SqlDataSourceEnumerator' does not exist in the current context

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you add `using System.Data.Sql;` ? [SqlDataSourceEnumerator Classe](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator)

Comment: Yeah i just did , but nothing changed ..

Comment: Is there the System.Data.dll assembly in the project's references (it is added by default in every new project Framework or Console, but can be manually removed)? [Applies to (not Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to).

Comment: I disovered that i had no ability to reference assemblies in project explorer and i realized that the type of project i was using was probably not correct. I created a WINDOWS FORM application c# ,  and now with using System.Data.Sql it seems ok ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the nuget package of `Microsoft.Data.Sql`

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include more detail? Specifically, it’d be useful to acknowledge the previous update, and provide a source for the more recent reintroduction of this class.

Answer (score 4):

At this point in time the `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` has not been implemented for any version of .NET Core or .NET 5. This is because the .NET Framework version relies on a native C++ implementation and the .NET team will need to reimplement it as managed code to fit their design objectives. If/when it is implemented it will be in the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package.

There's a discussion that covers this on the `dotnet/SqlClient` github repository:

- [SqlClient implementation and API is not complete in Core](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/17)

Note that this has been known since early 2017, and the last reference to there being any resolution is from [Jul 2020](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/17#issuecomment-656861690).

Until this is implemented you'll have to rely on .NET Framework for any application that absolutely must use `SqlDataSourceEnumerator`, or find an [alternative method](https://github.com/mrsquish/SqlBrowserClient) to scan for SQL servers.